# Using Dagger 2 in library project

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-library, dagger

I'm trying to make Dagger 2 working on my library used on a project also using Dagger 2.

As the library has to be independent, i'm trying to set up a new Dagger installation.

For that, I've created an AppController used to build my AppComponent:

```
public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication {

@NonNull
private AppComponent mAppComponent;

private static AppController sInstance;
private static int mStatusBarHeight = -1;

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;

    mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();

}

/*** Dependency injection ***/
public ScoAppComponent getAppComponent() {
    return mAppComponent;
}}
```

My AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VariantSpecificModule.class})

public interface AppComponent {

    //Activities
    void inject(StartActivity StartActivity);

    void inject(Navigation navigation);

    void inject(MyFragment myFragment);

    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);
}
```

And my AppModule:

```
    @Module
public class AppModule {

    public static final String APP_NAME = "";

    private AppController mApplication;

    public AppModule(AppController application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AppController providesApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("app_context")
    @Singleton
    Context providesApplicationContext(AppController app) {
        return app.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    EventBus providesEventBus() {
        return EventBus.getDefault();
    }

}
```

I've also declared my AppController in my library's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    tools:replace="android:name">
```

BUT I obviously have an issue: my controller is always returning null when I try to inject my BaseActivity ...

```
AppController.getInstance().getAppComponent().inject(this);
```

Does someone has an idea about how to deal with dagger in library project ?

EDIT: It looks like application in library's AndroidManifest is not instantiated and it's not possible to have a different Application in an app and in a library so is there a trick to achieve my purpose ? Thanks

Comment: you're injecting the AppController into your BaseActivity after explicitly call it via the singleton instance you created? Or which object is null

Comment: For what I know but i'm just a beginner with Dagger, my AppController should be instantiated at runtime through my library's Manifest but it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: @Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})    - then clean & rebuild

Comment: @Singleton @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, VariantSpecificModule.class}) -> if you need both